# Last date of an ocurrence given condition - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I'm looking for a formula for a COLUMN in Power BI that shows the last date up to "Date" that an specific customer made a purchase. Note that the last date may be variable given the "Date" I want the result.

I have found solutions that will show, for example, last date for costumer 101 = 3/31/2020 for all rows of that costumer. That doesn't work for me since the Date which I need to see the data is variable. So if I have a Slicer for "Date" = 2/28/2020, I want the last date up to THAT POINT that a customer made a purchase (so, in this case, 1/31/2020)

```
CustomerCode    Date        Purchase    Result 
101             1/31/2020   $50         1/31/2020
102             1/31/2020   $0          null
101             2/28/2020   $0          1/31/2020
102             2/28/2020   $25         2/28/2020
101             3/31/2020   $20         3/31/2020
102             3/31/2020   $15         3/31/2020
101             4/30/2020   $0          3/31/2020
102             4/30/2020   $0          3/31/2020
```

Take into consideration that this is a very simplifed data (given confidentiality restrictions) and I'm currently working with a table with 2M plus rows. Note that COUNTROWS also may not work since there are no register for some clients for certain dates.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The reason why I want to have that as a column, instead of a Measure, it is because I also want to create a Slicer so I can have a table as a visualization where I can see the information of clients that have not made a purchase for 1 or 2 or 3...months

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, you can use this below Measure code or a similar logic to get your required output-

```
last_purchase_date = 

var current_customer_code = MIN(your_table_name[CustomerCode])
var current_date = MIN(your_table_name[Date])

RETURN
MAXX(
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[CustomerCode] = current_customer_code
        && your_table_name[Date] <= current_date
        && your_table_name[Purchase] > 0
    ),
    your_table_name[Date]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's give it a try (I'm typing off the top of my head, so apologies for any syntax errors):

Now, since you're talking about a slicer, you really want a **measure**,not a column, as calculated columns cannot change dynamically, based on a slicer selection.

The easiest solution would be to have a separate date table, that would not be related to your table (and use that table's date column in the slicer). If that were the case, this would be simple.

First, get the selected date: `var selectedDate = SELECTEDVALUE(Dates[date])`

Then find your date in question: `var myDate = CALCULATE(MAX(Fact[date]), FILTER(Fact, Fact[Date] <= selectedDate && Fact[CustomerCode] = '101'))`

Now for the complete measure, for instance Purchase to that point:

```
Purchase Measure before Customer X =
VAR selectedDate =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Dates[date] )
VAR myDate =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( Fact[date] ),
        FILTER ( Fact, Fact[Date] <= selectedDate && Fact[CustomerCode] = '101' )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( Fact[Purchase] ), FILTER ( Fact, Fact[Date] <= myDate ) )
```

Now, assuming that your slicer is based on the same Date column from the `Fact` table, that would look a bit different:

```
Purchase Measure before Customer X =
VAR selectedDate =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Fact[date] )
VAR myDate =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( Fact[date] ),
        FILTER ( ALL(Fact), Fact[Date] <= selectedDate && Fact[CustomerCode] = '101' )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( Fact[Purchase] ), FILTER ( ALL(Fact), Fact[Date] <= myDate ) )
```

Notice the ALL(Fact) formula in the filter. The filtering context needs to be modified in this example, as the second case is based on the assumption that you're slicing the Fact table and therefore, initially values are only limited to those on the selected date.

Please let me know, if that does it for you. Otherwise, it would be usefule, if you provided more information (like what you would really like to achieve - end result).

**EDIT:**
So, now that I know the purpose, I would approach it differently. I would create a what-if parameter table that would look like this:

[image]

When you create a what-if parameter, a measure is also created, in this instance:
`Value Months since last purchase = SELECTEDVALUE('Months since last purchase'[Months since last purchase], 3)`

This measure will tell you (let's assume) that you only want customers who did not make a purchase within the last 3 months.

Let's also assume that you have a measure that shows you the report date (date that you want to calculate the 3 months from). Let's assume it's always `TODAY()`. `Report date = TODAY()`.

Now I would create a measure that would show me number of days that each customer did not purchase, but only if the number of days is more than X months back.

```
Days since the last purchase =
VAR last_purchase_date =
    MAX ( Fact[Date] )
RETURN
    IF (
        EDATE ( last_purchase_date, [Value Months since last purchase] ) < [Report date],
        DATEDIFF(last_purchase_date, [Report date], DAY),
        BLANK ()
    )
```

This should work in a table, where each customer is in a separate row (no need to filter the Max(Fact[Date]) measure in that scenario) or - more general - only one customer is in the measure context.

Since we are returning `BLANK()`, when last purchase is within the last X months, the table would only show customers who did not make purchase in the last X months (assuming no other measure is in the table).

Here's a working sample:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmqvMyRqhrBpgtRFbx0p5Uj61ckoaw?e=yOdcXP

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. What I really want to achieve is to identify which customers have not made a purchase for 1, 2, 3... months for different dates, that is why I wanted to have the last date in a column. So I can create a Slicer for "Have not made purchases in X months", this way it shows the details and more information about costumers that bought my products in past months but have not done that yet

Comment: @Laura_M99 ok, I think I understand, one more question. How do you want to visualise it? Do you want to provide a list of customers sorted based on how long ago their last purchase was?

Comment: The table that I actually use is very large and has a lot of information about the costumers: name, phone number, email, facebook account, state where they live, etc. That general information is what I want to see so strategies can be deployed for this costumers to buy again. ---Also, another thing, using the Result column, I will create another column using DATEDIFF to calculate "number of months since costumer has not purchased" and those quantities I will use to create my slicer

Comment: @Laura_M99 I don't think calculated columns will work dynamically. Let me think of a solution - I will put it in my answer. Generally, I would use a parameter (what if) table and put it in the slicer then calculate number of days since last purchase dynamically using measures.

Comment: Oh ok, I'm relatively new to Power BI, so that was my first tought of what could work and I don't know how to use slicers with other elements besides a column. I will try to use the solution with the measure you provided then, thank you again

Comment: @Laura_M99 you are correct that only table columns can be put in the slicer. And I would put in the slicer the number of months from the what-if parameter table. Then use the measure to calculate how many days passed since the last purchase.

Comment: @Laura_M99 I updated my answer, please have a look at the provided working sample.